# image and text display not working

Tags: html

I have an html file like this.I am getting the output like this in picture1.But i need an output like this in picture2.mainly text should be parallel to the image

```
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"en-US\" xml:lang=\"en-US\">
<head>
<title>MigraineMate Paint Graph</title>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\" />
<link href=\"default.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"/>
</head>
<body>
<img  src=\"Justin.png\" alt=\"justin Biber\"/>
<div id=\"notification\">
<h1>Please Wait  Graph may take a moment to load</h1>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css file is

```
#notification 
{
    width: 860px;
    height: 730px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#notification h1 
{
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left:0px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start with left-floating the beaver:

```
<img src="..." alt="..." style="float:left; text-align:left;" />
```

Here are some [quick notes](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `{float: left;}` to the image to allow the text to wrap around it. Remeber to also clear the float afterwards using something like `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`